# Issues with Echo Dots and audio output in multi-output device on mac

Tags: audio, midi, aws

Having a bit of an issue when creating a multi-output device in the Audio MIDI setup and adding two echo dots to the configuration. The audio simply doesn't work when switching my settings to output to the MOD.

- Both speakers are connected via Bluetooth.
- Running OS Ventura
- The echo dot speakers work independently

Edit: I've been able to make the audio come out of the Echo Dot designated as the primary speaker in the MOD, but the secondary still will not play.

Any insight/tips/advice?